# How can I import a function from __init__.py into a blueprint (or other module)? (flask)

Tags: python, flask, module

So I have a project folder like this:

```
FlaskApp/
    __init__.py
    something.py
```

I have initialised a mysql connection for my application like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

mysql = MySQL()
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'u'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'p'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'db'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)
```

And I have a really handy function declared like this right after it:

```
def handle_mysql_cmd(command):
   #some command handling
```

Now, I have created some blueprints and put them into different .py files, and I'd like to use the *handle_mysql_cmd()* in these blueprints. for example in something.py i have code like this:

```
bp = Blueprint('index', __name__, url_prefix='/')

@bp.route('/index/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def homepage():
    cmd = "SELECT * FROM USERS"
    handle_mysql_cmd(cmd)
    #...
```

My problem is that if I try to use relative imports in something.py:

```
from . import handle_mysql_cmd as handle_mysql_cmd
```

I get the following error:

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

And if i try it this way:

```
from FlaskApp import handle_mysql_cmd as handle_mysql_cmd
```

It says:

> No module named 'FlaskApp'

How could I import this one particular function into my modules? Or are there any more efficent and less hacky ways to do it?
Thanks in advance! 
(Also if I figure something out I will try to post it right away)

Comment: what happens if you try: `from app import handle_mysql_cmd` ?

Comment: In this case it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`

Comment: If you're properly using a virtualenv, make sure your dependencies are all installed using pip into the appropriate virtualenv.  Also ensure that your virtualenv is not the same name as your FlaskApp.

Comment: What happens if you try to import mysql variable that you've declared into each of the bp   .py file and try to run the command?